# No system updates for Galaxy Nexus (maguro) with Cyanogenmod 11 after 20140225-SNAPSHOT-Installer

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-nexus, ota-update

I have a Galaxy Nexus (maguro) and some time back I got an OTA udpate after I installed Cyanogenmod on on the phone using the installer. I'm not sure which 'M' release this OTA update is. All it says in Settings >  About phone > Cyanogenmod statistics > Preview data is the following:

> 11-20140225-SNAPSHOT-InstallerXNPQ09P-maguro

I'm assuming this is an update added on 25-Feb-2014.

But in the Cyanogenmod download page for maguro (https://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=maguro), it shows 'M' releases that were added way after that, like M6 added on 04-May-2014.

So, 1) Why am I not getting these updates through Settings >  About phone > System updates and 2) Why doesn't the above mentioned snapshot show up in the Cyanogenmod download page for maguro?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to 1) is:
The installer doesn't use the same releases as you see on the download page, it has separately signed releases so they're not directly comparable. Sorry I don't know how you can predict when you might next get an update when you've used the installer.

The answer to 2) is:
Latest release for installer devices are here: http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/CyanogenMod_Installer#Supported_Devices

For the galaxy nexus that is:

> 11.0-InstallerXNPQ09P

Further info:
On that same wiki page it says:

> How do I get updates?
>   Updates are done via Settings > About phone > System Updates. When a new snapshot build is >available, your will also receive a notification. Devices flashed via the installer will only get updates when a new stable snapshot build is available.

I suspect that might be out of date however.

The following seems to be the most recent up to date information:
http://www.cyanogenmod.org/blog/cm-11-m4-post-release-items

> Installer builds are those served via the CM Installer applications (Windows, Mac). These >builds are specially signed and named separately – there is no concept of an ‘M’ build for >this release channel – so saying ‘Installer skipped M#’ is an incorrect interpretation. >This channel only ever receives specially created Stable builds – they even come with their >own naming structure (eg XNPQ02R).

There is an additional blog post that rehashes some of the information on the m4 blog post above with a bit of extra clarification here: http://www.cyanogenmod.org/blog/cyanogenmod-11-0-m6-release

HTH.
Stephen